# Connect to a Winforms app using javascript client app

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Winforms windows app that runs on a pc that acts as a server (it doesn't run on a real server).  It must run on a pc, because it needs to control processes.  I need to have the ability to connect to this app using a browser based html/js client.  The client must be able to control the server through the web UI.

The winforms app currently exposes a WCF endpoint for windows clients, but we need to make it work with web clients as well.  I thought there was a way to use WCF WebServiceHost, but I guess the server app must be ASP.net.

Is there a better way to implement this kind of functionality using REST and web services (or some other tech)?

Comment: Many ways to do this; which way is best for you depends on too many things that you haven't explained. Do some research on web services, hosting, and cloud services. Get a trial account. Perform some testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow:

If your needs are simple enough, you are correct that HTTP calls (REST, etc) might be your best fit.  You can host your own ASP.NET WebAPI endpoints inside of your app. Here is a decent start at doing that:

[WebAPI Self-Hosting](https://codeopinion.com/self-host-asp-net-web-api/)

If you need event-driven interaction you may want to look into ASP.NET SignalR. SignalR is a high-performance communication framework using "real-time" protocols, like WebSockets, among others.

[SignalR Self-Hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

With HTTP APIs you can use plain javascript or perhaps a javascript library to send the requests to your Forms app.  For SignalR Microsoft provides SignalR javascript client libraries to communicate with SignalR servers.